# How can I import CSV into table if the CSV does not have all the tables fields?

Tags: sql, database, mariadb, load-data-infile

I am trying to import a CSV file that contains a bunch of data.  The data does not have a Primary Key or a unique identifier, so I created a table with an "id" field that is the primary key and auto increments.

Lets say the table has three fields id, LastName, and FirstName.  My CSV file just has LastName,FirstName.   I am getting a bunch of errors that say Row X does not contain data for all columns.

I have tried to explicitly name the fields I want to add thinking the auto increment would assign a value, it does not work when I do this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/insert.csv' INTO TABLE data (LastName, FirstName);
```

I get the same error, Row X does not contain data for all columns...

I tried to then explicitly set id to be Null by:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/insert.csv' INTO TABLE data (id, LastName, FirstName) 
SET id=null;
```

Same error Row X does not contain data for all columns.  I have tried:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/insert.csv' INTO TABLE data 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '/n' SET id=null;
```

When I do that it tries to take the first value in my CSV and assign it to the id field and then gives me an Incorrect Integer Value for column 'id' at row 1.

How can I add data to a table if the CSV file I am using does not contain every single field in the table?  Thank you!

EDIT:

Here are the table fields:

```
id        | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment 

LastName  | tinytext | YES  |     | NULL    |                

FirstName | tinytext | YES  |     | NULL    |
```

Here is the CSV File:

```
Smith,John
Coconut,Joe
Ann,Pattye
```

Those are on diff lines I cannot get the stackoverflow formatting to cooperate.

Comment: Please post content of your csv in body of question. You may have missing cells like comma at end of lines, special characters, or may not be using a csv but another delimiter file.

Comment: It's very common that data from foreign sources doesn't exactly match the structure or constraints of base tables, and the typical practice in such cases is to load the data into a staging table, and then move it into the base table, amending it as appropriate.

Comment: Smith,John
Coconut,Joe
Ann,Pattye

Comment: It is a CSV, I even re-exported it to be sure.  I pasted it above.  I even went and created a second new csv to test and get the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/insert.csv' INTO TABLE data (NULL, LastName, FirstName);

Comment: I get:        ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL, LastName, FirstName)' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

I've never personally used MariaDB, but with most databases that I have used it all depends on how you set up your ID column. I would check to make sure you have it marked as auto increment. Usually when you have it set as such and you leave that field empty for an insert it will automatically increment (obviously) and add the data for you. And can error out without it.

Comment: id is int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT

Answer (score 0):

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL
    INFILE '/path/insert.csv'
    INTO TABLE data (@x, LastName, FirstName);
```

That is, put things you don't need or want into `@variables`.

That technique also provides a way to programmatically modify the text before actually storing.  (See the manual.)

Another approach is to build a table that has a set of columns that matches the input file; `LOAD` into it; then use `INSERT ... SELECT ...` to copy stuff over into the 'real' table.  This gives you even more power to adjust your data before storing it into the real place.